# Storage of `ray_data` in ray tracing payload

Tags: swift, metal

I am currently working with Metal's ray tracing API. I remembered I could pass data from an intersection function to the compute kernel that started the ray intersection process. After rewatching the WWDC 2020 talk `Discover ray tracing with Metal` by Sean James (linked [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10012/)), I found the relevant section around 16:13 where he talks about the ray payload.

However, I was curious where this payload is stored as it’s passed to the intersection function. When declared with the relevant `[[ payload ]]` attribute in the intersection function, it must be in the `ray_data` address space. According to the Metal Shading Language Specification (version 2.3), pg. 64, the data passed into the intersection function is copied in the `ray_data` address space and is copied back out once the intersection function returns. However, this doesn't specify if, e.g., the data is stored in tile memory (like data in the `threadgroup` address space is) or stored in the per-thread memory (`thread` address space). The video did not specify this either.

In fact, the declarations for the `intersect` function (see pg. 204) that include the payload term are in the `thread` address space (which makes sense)

So where does the copied `ray_data` "version" of the data stored in the `thread` address space in the kernel go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer I received on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679241),

> The way the GPU stores the payload varies between device and there is no particular size. All we can really say is that cost scales roughly with the size so you should minimize that payload. If the payload gets too large you may run into a dramatic performance drop.